# Get drop down from array of object values using meanjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

- I am trying to get the values as a drop down or select field which were with in the `comments` array.
- I am trying for `comments` array of object `commentText` values in the `drop down`, how can i do this in the `ng-option` ?. [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qRTmGuIXafZ3DVrPEgBN?p=preview)

For Example:

- I have did the drop down `ng-option` for first without array value like `ng-options="item.title for item in questions"`.
- What I am  exactly looking for comments array of object values `[commentText": "7A"]` in the drop down how can i do that.
- I tried `ng-options="item for item.comments.commentText in questions"` it's not working for me. How to fix it?

My Data:

```
$scope.questions = [
  {
    "_id": "59df6c37b6748bc809050699",
    "user": {
    "_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
    "profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
  },
  "__v": 1,
  "comments": [
    {
      "created": 1507897712831,
      "email": "ms@e21designs.com",
      "name": "Maniselvam selvam",
      "link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
      "commentText": "7A"
    }
  ],
  "questionid": "",
  "created": "2017-10-12T13:20:55.383Z"
}
]
```

My Html:

```
  <label>1. Without array value</label>
  <select ng-model="class"  ng-options="item.title for item in questions">
  </select>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 11px;">
  <label>2. With comments array value</label>
  <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class"  ng-options="item for item.comments.commentText in questions">
  </select>
</div>
```

Looks for second solution is :-

- I just want if we select question , comments select filter only this question's comments...how to do this... thanks

Comment: Another solution? can u describe?

Comment: See my updated answer now.

Comment: @mani if you fix the final bug will give you tick as well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('exApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myctrl', function($scope){
 $scope.questions = [
{
"_id": "59df6c37b6748bc809050699",
"user": {
"_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 1,
"openeyers": [],
"openeyes": 0,
"upvoters": [],
"upvotes": 0,
"isLiked": false,
"users": [],
"comments": [
{
"created": 1507897712831,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Maniselvam selvam",
"link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
"commentText": "7A"
},
{
"created": 1507897712831,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Maniselvam selvam",
"link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
"commentText": "9A"
},
{
"created": 1507897712831,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Maniselvam selvam",
"link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
"commentText": "10A"
}
],
"questionid": "",
"title": "Silver jublie",
"created": "2017-10-12T13:20:55.383Z"
},
{
"_id": "59df6c37b6748bc809050699",
"user": {
"_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
"displayName": "Maniselvam selvam",
"dob": "1991-05-10T07:00:00.000Z",
"profileImageURL": "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png"
},
"__v": 1,
"openeyers": [],
"users": [],
"comments": [
{
"created": 1507897712831,
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"name": "Maniselvam selvam",
"link": "https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0B5c-p1bvkfS9REJHMGhMY1BTV1k",
"commentText": "8A"
}
],
"questionid": "",
"title": "Public School",
"created": "2017-10-12T13:20:55.383Z"
}
];
$scope.editClass = function(section){
$scope.sectionwithObject = section;
$scope.sectionOnly=section.commentText;
$scope.newLink = section.link;
}
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="myctrl">

<div>
  <div>
  <label>1. Without array value</label>
  <select ng-model="ques"  ng-options="item.title for item in questions">
  </select>
  </div>
  
  <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
  
  <label>2. With comments array value</label>
  <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="commen"  ng-options="item as item.commentText for item in ::ques.comments" ng-change="editClass(commen)">
  </select>{{commen}}
 <br><br>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="sectionwithObject.commentText"/><br><br>
     <input type="text" ng-model="sectionOnly"/>
  </div><br>
  <div>
    <lable> Link</lable>
    <input type="text"  ng-model="sectionwithObject.link" /><br><br>
        <input type="text"  ng-model="newLink" />
  </div>
  </div>
  
 

</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi if I used your answer and clicking of update button it's not updated, i got following error:- `Cast to String failed for value "[object Object]" at path "class"`, if possible please help us...

Comment: Because its object bro. If you want get comments . Then use $scope.commen.commentText .

Comment: where i should use this `$scope.commen.commentText ` ? in controller (or) html part if possible can you show the demo please (or) update my plunker as well...sorry to interrupt you....thanks (are you from chennai) if posdible share your mail id... thanks

Comment: What u want exactly . ? My demo is showing well. See there.

Comment: If you clearly explain . We can suggest quick and easily.

Comment: Please look at this plunker  i have updated http://plnkr.co/edit/vokoid1DTQZnYyAjaNmJ?p=preview what I exactly looking is first we select `school` then we select school section, then there is a one input filed is available so what i need is section need to `bind` in that `input text field`...for example :- if we select 7A in section dropdown, this section needs to bind in input field, now it's showing error like '[object Object]'...so how to do this....

Comment: see my updated answer. The result is coming what u expect.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer i got solution http://plnkr.co/edit/PCVJWlT4I9RzkMhBCN2S?p=preview ,  
And one more thing please look at this plunker plnkr.co/edit/OHJ4BwQTsvqeJymzNWKq?p=preview i have added one more input filed also and how can i fetch this section link into another input filed... for example:- if we selected 7A in section this particular link needs to fetch in another input field ...please help us thanks.

Comment: will do definetly i am looking another solution too please look this plunker :- http://plnkr.co/edit/r7qAVcTzpoceTstImMeR?p=preview

Comment: And one more thing please look at this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/sVAoFamLvdJMvohH9wEe?p=preview i have added one more input filed also and how can i fetch this section link into another input filed... for example:- if we selected 7A in section this particular link needs to fetch in another input field ...please help us thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer it's working perfectly but only one bug is there if used school ` ng-options="item.title for item in questions"` like this it's saved as a `id` not like name 'vellamal (or) public school` , and then if used school ` ng-options="item.title as item.title for item in questions"` it's saved as name like 'vellamal' but section dropdown and link is not working is there any solution.....?

Comment: Try item as item.title for item in questions. Now u can get object. Just print {{selected}} then u will know how to get link.

Comment: Just print {{ques}}. Then see bro. Like second dropdown u can do.

Comment: Hi I am looking for same related answer so please check this and update thanks ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506303/how-to-get-the-value-like-first-drop-down-value-related-to-another-drop-down-val

Answer (score 1):

Just change your second select something like:-

```
 <select style="margin-left: 20px;" ng-model="class"  ng-options="item.commentText  for item in question.comments">
  </select>
```

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qYLCDbrrc1LwE0ZkLwJg?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I used your answer in my project it's saved as a `Boolean`like  true or false, but i want to save value like 7A or 8A... so can you give some other solution...thanks

Comment: You can simple use `$scope.class.commentText` see updated plunker

Comment: hi if I used your answer and clicking of update button it's not updated, i got following error:- `Cast to String failed for value "[object Object]" at path "class"`, if possible please help us...

Comment: my code in module :- `class: {
    type: String,
    trim: true},      and in controller :-   class = req.body.class; and in html :-  <div class="col-md-6">
                     <select  id="class" name="class" ng-model="class" class="form-control"  ng-options="item as item.commentText for item in vm.user.question.comments"></select>   </div>

Comment: S.O is all about getting some clue never expect an copy paste you have to modify your accordingly

Comment: Hi I am looking for same related answer so please check this and update thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506303/how-to-get-the-value-like-first-drop-down-value-related-to-another-drop-down-val