# How to Get the Value Like First Drop Down Value Related to Another Drop Down Value using of Angular JS?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

How to get the value like first select drop down value related to another select drop down value using of angular js?

Hi all I have created two `drop down fields` in [MyPlunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m57w9lcLHmcWnpQEYZUL?p=preview) and with in the `ng-option` I have used filter like `| filter:flterWithKp` because to get only the `kp` users.

- First drop down list are `kp users` `categories` and second drop down list is `kp users`.
- What I am looking is if we select `Religion & Culture` in first drop down, the second drop down should display only based on categories users.
- For example:- 1.in first drop down if we select as `Religion & Culture` and the second drop down list must like 'Francis', 2.in first drop down if we select as `Moral Ethics` and the second drop down list must like 'jennifer david'.
- Please check [this MyPlunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuP5mdikwDmyhoxioC77?p=preview) for reference i got the solution but it's not working in my portal, i would like same answer , please update my plunker as well to know the exact solution...

**My Html**

```
    <div>
  <p></p>
  <lable>Kp Users categories</lable>
   <select ng-model="Filtercategorieskp"  ng-options="item.categories for item in users | filter:flterWithKp">
  </select>
</div>  

<div>
  <lable>Kp Users</lable>
   <select ng-model="Filterkp" ng-change="newClass=Filterkp.username"  ng-options="item.username for item in users | filter:flterWithKp">
  </select>
</div>
```

**My Data:-**

```
          $scope.users = [
    {
    "_id": "5a12ab443cb3837415229d2e",
    "displayName": "Avinaash Kumar",
    "username": "John",
    "created": "2017-11-20T10:15:32.747Z",
    "roles": ["kp"],
    "categories": ["Environment & and Health"],
    "lastName": "Kumar",
    "firstName": "Avinaash"
    },
    {
    "_id": "5a12a7343cb3837415229d2d",
    "displayName": "sarawana kumar",
    "provider": "local",
    "username": "Henry",
    "roles": ["school_student"],
    "categories": [
    "Religion & Culture",
    "Moral Ethics"
    ],
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "firstName": "sarawana"
    },
    {
    "_id": "59ed8a1fd80e55a8100d51f0",
    "displayName": "selvam mani",
    "provider": "local",
    "username": "Francis",
    "roles": ["kp"],
    "categories": ["Religion & Culture"],
    "lastName": "mani",
    "firstName": "selvam"
    },
    {
    "_id": "59ed87cdd80e55a8100d51ef",
    "displayName": "jennifer david",
    "provider": "local",
    "username": "jennifer david",
    "roles": ["kp"],
    "categories": ["Moral Ethics"],
    "lastName": "david",
    "firstName": "jennifer"
    },
    {
    "_id": "59e09811a7319ae81feed177",
    "displayName": "ahamed nizar",
    "provider": "local",
    "username": "ahamednizar",
    "created": "2017-10-13T10:40:17.142Z",
    "roles": ["kp"],
    "categories": ["Religion & Culture"],
    "lastName": "nizar",
    "firstName": "ahamed"
    },
    {
    "_id": "59df6a76b6748bc809050697",
    "displayName": "Maniselvam selvam",
    "provider": "local",
    "username": "David",
    "roles": ["admin"],
    "categories": ["Moral Ethics"],
    "lastName": "selvam",
    "firstName": "Maniselvam"
    }

$scope.flterWithKp = function(item){
  console.log(item);
  return item.roles.indexOf('kp') >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
  <p></p>
  <lable>Kp Users categories</lable>
   <select ng-model="filter.Filtercategorieskp"  ng-options="item.categories for item in users | filter:{roles: 'kp'}">
  </select>
</div>  
<div>
  <lable>Kp Users</lable>
   <select ng-model="Filterkp" ng-change="newClass=Filterkp.username"  ng-options="item.username for item in users | filter:{ categories: filter.Filtercategorieskp.categories, roles:['kp']}">
  </select>
</div>
```

Look at the HTML of Plunker's filter. it uses

```
filter:{roles: 'kp'}
```

and

```
filter:{ categories: filter.Filtercategorieskp.categories, roles:['kp']
```

But you use  `ilter:flterWithKp`

If you want to filter with controller's method, you have to write two methods for two filter or you can use as like plunker.

I have update the plunker. You can check it:

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lTt0gaOcEolsHDSTHB3e?p=preview)

Comment: already we know your above answer look this updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/fuP5mdikwDmyhoxioC77?p=preview it not works in my portal so is there any other solution to get the answer?...

Comment: Hi Syedur, your answer is working for us, and no more problem if  we used `item.categories as` in :-  `ng-options="item.categories as item.categories for item in users | filter:flterWithKp"` the filter is not working so please check and update, bcoz we need to save categories value not like `id`, previous answer saved as a `id`....so please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/aLspBBxLvbpytj93zKis?p=preview